# Is there anyway to save a file locally that is automatically downloaded from a website link?

Tags: python, file, automation, scripting, ansible

For example, this link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519) automatically downloads a JSON file on my machine.

I was wondering if it was possible to write a python script that can save that file directly from the website locally elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the JSON:

```
import json
with open('data.txt') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

say you're getting the response in data and you want to write it to data.txt

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

if you don't want to go this route, then you can simply use the the subprocess module to with a command like

```
cp <path to file you can to copy> <path to where you can to copy it>
```

Download it to a specific folder,

```
import urllib
linkToFile = "http://www.someurl.com/file.pdf"
localDestination = "/home/user/local/path/to/file.pdf"
resultFilePath, responseHeaders = urllib.urlretrieve(linkToFile, localDestination)
```

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of saving the JSON file itself, directly from the website link, but in a location of my choosing, instead of the downloads.

Comment: Updated my answer 
@Popilofu